# Turkish visa holder traveling to Italy

Tags: visas, schengen, italy

If I have a valid Turkish tourist visa can I travel to Italy?

Comment: What's your nationality?

Comment: +1 Considering the fact that Turkey has exemptions for Schengen visa holders, the question does not strike me as absurd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a Turkish visa does not allow you to either enter or transit in the Schengen area. While Turkey has many special rules for Schengen visa holders, that's not reciprocal (i.e. the Schengen area has no special rules or exemptions for Turkish visa holders).

If citizens of your country need a visa *to enter* the Schengen area, the only visas that can be used for that are those issued by Schengen countries or, in very limited cases, residence permits from other EU countries.

If citizens of your country need a visa *for airport transit*, there are a number of exemptions for holders of visas from other countries (including the UK, Canada or the US) but not Turkey.

Somali citizens are in the most restrictive category so you need a visa for everything, even airport transit, in the whole Schengen area.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not from one of the countries that doesn't require visa to enter Schengen states (see [Do I need a visa to transit (or layover) in the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-in-the-schengen-area)) and you're not transiting through Italy for which there may be additional exceptions listed in the same question the Turkish Visa doesn't equate in any way to the [Schengen Visa](http://www.esteri.it/mae/en/ministero/servizi/stranieri/ingressosoggiornoinitalia/visto_ingresso).

So if you need a visa to enter Schengen States you will have to get one.